# How to get the pid of forked child process NODE JS

Tags: node.js, process

I'm forking child process in node and my business logic requires me to call this fork process again and again.Issue is to clean up previous forked process before calling next one.Is there any way that i can get my forked process pid ,so we can store it and kill it on next run

```
 const program = path.join(__dirname, 'test.js');
  var myProgram= fork.fork(program, [], {
  silent: true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) will retrun a [ChildProcess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) object. This object contains a bunch of properties including [pid](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_pid) and [kill](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal).

You can use the `kill` method to conveniently 'kill' your subprocess

```
  const forked = child_process.fork("path");

  forked.pid // 189...
  forked.killed // false

  forked.kill();

  forked.killed // true
```